# System Path vs. Sys.getenv('PATH')

Tags: macos, r, rstudio

This might turn out to be a rather trivial question, but has me baffled for quite some time now. It all started when I installed the universal document converter `pandoc` and added it to  my path. So when I do `echo $PATH` on the default terminal on my Mac OS X, it shows `pandoc` and I am able to execute it.

However, when I tried invoking the same in an R session using `system(pandoc --version)`, it could not recognize `pandoc`. Further checking revealed that `system('echo $PATH')` does not return the same path that I got on the terminal.

Can anyone help me with what is going on? I like to do all my work on `RStudio`, and hence would prefer if I can use `pandoc` directly from within. Hence the need to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

R and bash ( and undoubtedly  Rstudio) each create separate environments. The Terminal.app starts a bash session with its own default PATH settings. When Simon Urbanek recently answered this question, he referred the questioner to the R-Mac-FAQ 12.19. His full response is in the R-SIG-MAC archives. On my mail client it appears with a subject line Re: [R-SIG-Mac] PATH and is dated January 30, 2012. He also referred the questioner to: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1067/_index.html

As `?EnvVar` tells you: "`Sys.getenv` and `Sys.setenv` to read and set environmental variables in an R session." But then you already seem to be aware of those functions.