# RStudio doesn't load all Python modules via rPython call

Tags: python, r, rstudio

I have some unexpected behaviours running the same script from Bash and from within RStudio.

Please consider the following. I have a folder `"~/rpython"` containing two scripts:

```
# test1.R

library(rPython)

setwd("~/rpython")

python.load("test1.py")

number <- python.get("number")
string <- python.get("string")

print(sqrt(number))
print(string)
```

and

```
# test1.py

import random, nltk

number = random.randint(1, 1000)

string = nltk.word_tokenize('home sweet home')
```

I can call my R script from Bash with `Rscript test1.R`, which returns as expected

```
>> Loading required package: RJSONIO
>> [1] 13.0384
>> [1] "home"  "sweet" "home"
```

and if I call it again will produce a different random number

```
>> Loading required package: RJSONIO
>> [1] 7.211103
>> [1] "home"  "sweet" "home"
```

But when I run the very same script (`test1.R`) from RStudio things get weird. Here the output

```
# test1.R
> 
> library(rPython)
Loading required package: RJSONIO
> 
> setwd("~/rpython")
> 
> python.load("test1.py")
Error in python.exec(code, get.exception) : No module named nltk
> 
> number <- python.get("number")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
Error in python.get("number") : Variable not found
> string <- python.get("string")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'string' is not defined
Error in python.get("string") : Variable not found
> 
> print(sqrt(number))
Error in print(sqrt(number)) : object 'number' not found
> print(string)
Error in print(string) : object 'string' not found
```

For some reason when I call the script from RStudio, the Python interpreter can't locate the module `nltk` (it seems to be the same with other `pip` installed modules) but has no problem importing `random`.

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv or any other complex install/library path setup?  I see [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20337202/using-python-virtual-env-in-r)...

Comment: No, as far as I know.

Comment: Does the behavior of `number` and `string` still happen even if you run the code in a fresh R session?

Comment: @BrenBarn Good point if I restart the session I don't get any output, just errors. I updated my question

Comment: I can't really debug this since I don't have rPython (it doesn't work on Windows), but I'd suggest you try to narrow down the cause by playing around with a simple .py file.  Try looking at `sys.path` to see if it's the same as what you get when running the program externally, etc.

Comment: Yep, it seems that R from bash and R from Rstudio create different environments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9212961/1707938), I think the different behaviour depends from this. Yet I don't get how to write a script that both is executed in bash and Rstudio.

Comment: I realise this was asked years ago but any solution on this?

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem, too. The issue was that my bash terminal seems to be calling a different python than the one Rstudio is. I also learned that if you're only trying to call Python.load() from rPython, you're probably better off with system() from the base R library.

1. Figure out which python your bash terminal is calling. Go to your bash terminal and run `which python`. For me (OS X 10.11.5) it was `/usr/local/bin/python`. Now that we know the full path, we can call it explicitly and prevent R from choosing another version that might be installed in some corner of your machine.
2. Use `system()` to call bash commands from R instead of `python.load()`, and use the full path to your script. Using your example script name, and my example python path, it would be `system('/usr/local/bin/python /path/to/file/test.py1')`

Hope that helps!

Comment: How do you call the python you want explicitly using rPython?

Comment: This question/answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25383030/rpython-using-wrong-python-installation-on-mac-osx

Comment: I think your answer should have suggested a comparison of the bash result to the R result from: `system("python --version")`. Then describe how to resolve the discrepancies.