# rPython not able to locate module "nltk"

Tags: python, r, nltk

I am trying to use rPython to import some of the nltk functionality into my R program. 
My test function is,

test.py

```
import random, numpy,nltk
import sys

print (sys.version)

number = random.randint(1, 1000)

print(number)
string = nltk.word_tokenize('home sweet home')

print(string)
```

Running the code from console it runs fine,

```
python test.py

2.7.10 (default, Sep 23 2015, 04:34:21) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.72)]
331
['home', 'sweet', 'home']
```

Running from R however, I am encountering this problem,

```
library(rPython)
python.load("test.py")
Error in python.exec(code, get.exception) : No module named nltk
```

same with RStudio. 
If I remove "nltk" then things work fine,

```
python.load("test.py")

2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)]
386
```

Seems both of them using the same version of python 2.7
I see this user having a similar issue but only with RStudio.
[RStudio doesn't load all Python modules via rPython call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24346735/rstudio-doesnt-load-all-python-modules-via-rpython-call)

Comment: What's the `sys.path` in your various pythons? That's where python looks for modules. `import sys` then look at `sys.path`. Should also let you tell if it really is the same python interpreter (dont be fooled just because the version is the same...). Ooh actually the python and `clang` versions are different... Methinks two different pythons, one without `nltk` installed...